# How do I use a WHERE clause with a CASE inside a SUM?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I've got two tables, one is a list of tasks. Each task (row) is specified by a unique pair of `story_id` and `pos_id` (point of sale ID), and includes the date `last_completed`. The other table is a list of POSes with a `priority` number.

**This is what I need**: I'll call for each task `x` the quantity consisting of the time since last completion divided by the priority number for its POS. I need the sum of all the `x`'s for each story over all that story's POSes.

On top of that some of the tasks have never been completed, so `last_completed` is `NULL`; for those tasks, I want to set `x` to 10.

This is what I tried, but I get an error on the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT t.story_id, SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN t.last_completed IS NULL THEN 10
    ELSE DATEDIFF(NOW(), t.last_completed)/p.priority
  END
WHERE t.pos_id = p.id) AS weeks
FROM test_task t, test_pos p
GROUP BY story_id;
```

I also tried the `WHERE` clause on the same line as the `ELSE`, but that didn't work either.

Can anyone tell me how I can correlate the `priority` with the `last_completed` date inside a `CASE` inside a `SUM`?

Comment: We expect this to produce an error, the `WHERE` clause is not valid where you have it; the WHERE clause follows the `FROM` clause. I strongly recommend you ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation and use the JOIN keyword instead, and move the join predicates from the WHERE clause to the ON clause. (See the answer from Gordon for an example.)

Comment: Thanks. Mureinik made the first point, and rather more politely. Not sure why you're criticizing me for "the old-school comma syntax for the join operation."

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, this is the query you want:

```
SELECT t.story_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.last_completed IS NULL THEN 10
                ELSE DATEDIFF(NOW(), t.last_completed)/p.priority
           END) as weeks
FROM test_task t JOIN
     test_pos p
     ON t.pos_id = p.id
GROUP BY story_id;
```

Your condition should be in the `on` clause for an explicit `join`.  This has nothing to do with a `case` expression in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have misordered your clauses - `from` should come before `where`. Additionally, you need to close the `sum`'s brackets:

```
SELECT t.story_id, SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN t.last_completed IS NULL THEN 10
    ELSE DATEDIFF(NOW(), t.last_completed)/p.priority
  END) AS weeks
FROM test_task t, test_pos p
WHERE t.pos_id = p.id
GROUP BY story_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'd incorporated the WHERE *into* the SUM clause, which is why the SUM's closing parenthesis is after the WHERE. Yes, I know that doesn't work and it's crazy.